# iOS SSO with multiple apps

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I've searched for an answer to this question and have been unable to find any answers.

I've got a range of iOS apps that I want to use the same Facebook app. The SSO works perfectly with the first app I created and tested on. But all the other fail and get returned an unknown_error.

I'm calling:

```
self.facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:<app id> urlSchemeSuffix:<app suffix> andDelegate:self] autorelease];
```

This is all working and even when the sign ins are failing I am returned back to the correct app. However, each time my the:

```
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
```

method get called where cancelled equals NO.

Are there some other settings I need to change somewhere? Is this because my apps have not yet been submitted to the App Store (except the one that is working)? If that's the case, how am I meant to test this stuff?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Have you added Custom URL Types in your app's plist?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I am returned back to the correct app. However, the sign in fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the useful "unknown_error" message only occurred when authenticating via the iOS Facebook app.

A quick and dirty workaround is to force the Facebook SDK to use mobile safari for authentication. Look for [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES] in Facebook.m and change the FBAuth value.

Not the nicest solution... but if you need a project out of the door... ;)

Comment: This works. Perhaps I'll try and use the FB app for SSO again at a later date when hopefully this works as it should. For now though this will certainly do.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem as described above. The way I fixed it was to make sure that all of the Bundle IDs of the iOS apps that are sharing the Facebook app are listed.

[image: Multiple iOS Apps Sharing the Same Facebook App]

As you can see in the picture, I have two URL Scheme Suffixes and the blurred out portions are the Bundle IDs of the apps that are connecting to this facebook app. Since it's a free and paid version, I only use one App Store ID so the posts from the free version will link to the paid version App Store link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Were you able to get this working before you shipped the product off to Apple? I can't select that my app is a Native iOS App until I have an App Store ID and I assume that won't exist until I actually send the app to Apple. But it seems a bit weird to not be able to get the app to work with Facebook before it's deployed.

Comment: Yes, you get to choose your own app id.  You only need to choose a name and go through the beginning steps of uploading your app to get an app id.  You don't actually have to upload anything at this point.