# Same facebook key for lite and pro apps

Tags: iphone, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a lite and pro version of my Iphone app, but my lite app rejected by appstore ,they cannot login through facebook. But in development mode i can able to login both pro and lite version through FB.

I have used same FB developer key for both lite and pro.
Is this the issue for rejection?
If i need to use different developer key for lite and pro version of same app?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you added prefix for both app in Facebook settings?

Comment: When you use same facebook app id for 2 apps than you must use prefix to recognize from which app you are trying login. Because if you install 2 apps in same device than how facebook will recognize from which app you are trying to login when you redirected to safari or facebbok app..

Comment: Please check my answer. It would be helpful

Comment: I don't like the "lite" and "pro" approach. Why don't you use in-app purchasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993996/two-ios-apps-using-the-same-facebook-app-id-is-it-possible). It may help you.

> urlSchemeSuffix is a string of lowercase letters that is appended to the base URL scheme used for SSO. For example, if your facebook ID is "350685531728" and you set urlSchemeSuffix to "abcd", the Facebook app will expect your application to bind to the following URL scheme: "fb350685531728abcd". This is useful if your have multiple iOS applications that share a single Facebook application id (for example, if you have a free and a paid version on the same app) and you want to use SSO with both apps. Giving both apps different urlSchemeSuffix values will allow the Facebook app to disambiguate their URL schemes and always redirect the user back to the correct app, even if both the free and the app is installed on the device.
>   
> urlSchemeSuffix is supported on version 3.4.1 and above of the Facebook app. If the user has an older version of the Facebook app installed and your app uses urlSchemeSuffix parameter, the SDK will proceed as if the Facebook app isn't installed on the device and redirect the user to Safari.

You can also refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915296/ios-sso-with-multiple-apps/8866018#8866018) which helps you to understand how prefix works with `Facebook`.