# Facebook api intergration for login iOS app more than 2 app using same facebook app id

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

If i have installed more than 2 app using same facebook app id, after login any app using facebook credentials it open the random app, and when I debug the code it did not call the login app below methode.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{

}
```

its called the existing app this method and open random app with same facebook app id used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130442/multiple-apps-with-the-same-url-scheme-ios

Comment: My question something related to this Can I share an app ID across apps? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting/

But the problem is that I am using the Facebook SDk 3.0 and in this i used the urlSchemeSuffix to distinguish the app using facebook app id. But every time it open the random app.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217308/same-facebook-key-for-lite-and-pro-apps/22218349#22218349)

And Please check this [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993996/two-ios-apps-using-the-same-facebook-app-id-is-it-possible). It may help you.

> urlSchemeSuffix is a string of lowercase letters that is appended to the base URL scheme used for SSO. For example, if your facebook ID is "350685531728" and you set urlSchemeSuffix to "abcd", the Facebook app will expect your application to bind to the following URL scheme: "fb350685531728abcd". This is useful if your have multiple iOS applications that share a single Facebook application id (for example, if you have a free and a paid version on the same app) and you want to use SSO with both apps. Giving both apps different urlSchemeSuffix values will allow the Facebook app to disambiguate their URL schemes and always redirect the user back to the correct app, even if both the free and the app is installed on the device.
>   
> urlSchemeSuffix is supported on version 3.4.1 and above of the Facebook app. If the user has an older version of the Facebook app installed and your app uses urlSchemeSuffix parameter, the SDK will proceed as if the Facebook app isn't installed on the device and redirect the user to Safari.

You can also refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915296/ios-sso-with-multiple-apps/8866018#8866018) which helps you to understand how prefix works with facebook.